# mybatis two DAO is impossible?

Tags: java, database, oracle, mybatis, dao

Is using two DAO at the same time impossible?

Here is the code I'm using :

```
public class MyBatisconfig {
    private static SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

    public static SqlSessionFactory getSqlSessionFactory() {
    if (sqlSessionFactory == null) {
        String resource = "mybatis-config.xml";
        Reader reader; 
        try {
            reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);
            sqlSessionFactory =
                    new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sqlSessionFactory;
}
```

}

**AdminDAO.class**

```
private SqlSessionFactory factory = MyBatisconfig.getSqlSessionFactory();
```

**UserDAO.class**

```
private SqlSessionFactory factory = MyBatisconfig.getSqlSessionFactory();
```

**mybatis-config.xml**

```
<typeAliases>
    <typeAlias type="human.vo.User" alias="user" />
    <typeAlias type="human.vo.Admin" alias="admin" />

</typeAliases>

<environments default="development"> 
    <environment id="development"> 
        <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
        <dataSource type="POOLED">
            <property name="driver" value="${driver}" />
            <property name="url" value="${url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${password}" />
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>
<mappers>
    <mapper resource="mappers/userMapper.xml" />
    <mapper resource="mappers/adminMapper.xml" />
</mappers>
```

Using getSqlSessionFactory throws an error.

Comment: Please share the exception you are receiving

Comment: exception nothing

Comment: The method getSqlSessionFactory() from the type MyBatisconfig refers to the missing type SqlSessionFactory